# Validate datetime in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm having a problem related to datetime validation check.
In the model I used
[image]

In view:
[image]

but in show error when input "13/03/2019 14:55"
[image]
thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add your code as text, instead of images. Text code is easier to read and respond to.

Comment: Always include all the relevant parts of the code as text in your question. If you simply attach code images to describe the problem, people tend to ignore the question or if the images are removed in future your question become incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

In my edm model i use this syntax, try it:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> last_update { get; set; }
```

Hope this help.

Leo